# UIWebView's _UIWebViewScrollView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I created an instance of `UIWebView` called `myWebView`.  I populated `myWebView` with the  content from loadHTMLString, added several UIImageViews and UIViews.  It worked as expected:  UIImageViews and UIViews are all on top of the webview's content from html string.

I then archived and un-archived `myWebView`  using `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.  After un-archived, only the html string content is visible.  All other UIViews and UIImageViews were moved to back.  So they are not visible.  An NSLog of `myWebView.subviews` before archiving and after un-archiving showed that there a _UIWebViewScrollView was moved from the first object in the subviews to the last object.  Note that only the _UIWebViewScrollView order was changed.

Not sure if it was by design by the SDK but to restore the views order and make them visible as normal, I did this:

```
[myWebView sendSubviewToBack:[myWebView.subviews lastObject]];
```

Question:  Will doing this violate any of Apple's rule as I am not sure what if the _UIWebViewScrollView is considered as Apple's private thing.  But since I did not touch that _UIWebViewScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as far as rules go, you're fine.

HOWEVER: Since the `UIWebViewScrollView` is an internal member of the `UIWebView`, if they change the workings of `UIWebView` in a different iOS version, your code might get screwed up.

To play it a little on the safer side, you should try to set tags on each of the subviews you add, and then do:

```
[myWebView bringSubviewToFront:[myWebView viewWithTag:100]];
[myWebView bringSubviewToFront:[myWebView viewWithTag:101]];
[myWebView bringSubviewToFront:[myWebView viewWithTag:102]];
... etc (remember to use the tags that you used for your subviews)
```

On another note, messing with the `UIWebView` might result in troubles later on, there might be other ways to accomplish what you're trying to do, ways that are less risky

Comment: Agreed on the other ways part. It seems odd to me to ever consider adding custom subviews to something so private.

Comment: bringSubviewToFront was a good idea.  Just in case it was a bug and Apple decided to fix it on the next update.